# Is there a way to automatically format long argument lists in Java code so each one is on a separate line?

Tags: java, intellij-idea

I understand long parameter lists are generally bad, but can I do so without manually navigating before each argument and placing line breaks? I don't need to format every method in such a way, something like an [intention](https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/help/intention-actions.html) for parameter lists would be great.

```
Bakery(Baker baker, Policy policy, Cookbook cookbook, Schedule schedule) {}

Bakery(
    Baker baker, 
    Policy policy, 
    Cookbook cookbook, 
    Schedule schedule
) {}
```

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Under `Settings > Editor > Code Style > Java`, under the "Wrapping and Braces" tab, select the "Wrap always" option for "Method declaration parameters".

For added perks, you can even tick the "New line after '('" option to get it to appear similar to how you have it laid out in your question.

Comment: "Chop down if long" seems to be doing the same thing and I don't see any difference in the example code. What is the difference?

Comment: It has to do with the length of the line.  You've got a horizontal line over off to the right in IntelliJ; "long" is defined as going over that particular line.

Comment: @Makoto My chained method calls go over the right margin, but they don't chop down. They just wrap by one line. How is the `Chop down if long` option defined exactly?